# Animated slide-in menu with Sapui5/ openui5

Tags: css-transforms, sapui5

I need a slide in menu like (http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/slide-push-menus/) this menu slide right. I have in implemented in angular-js. But sapui5/ openui5 is giving me a hard time. First things first, I did not find any similar fitting the requirements in the controls API of sapui5.

My approach was to have a `sap.m.Popover` as container for a custom `sap.suite.ui.commons.VerticalNavigationBar`.  Animating the fade in trasition when the popup calls the `openBy` method. This totally does not end up to function and look how it should.

So my guess, the  `sap.m.Popover` is the main problem. What else can I or should I use? How is the simplest way to accomplish the task? If sapui5 is not capable of this, is there a easy way with plain jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

might ActionSheet be a possibility? https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ActionSheet/samples
Otherwise sap.m.Panel? https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.PanelExpanded/preview

Or QuickOverview?
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ca.ui.sample.QuickoverviewCompany/preview

 Or Overflow container?
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.ca.ui.OverflowContainer/about

This post shall not be spam, I just point out that there are controls being able to realize your requirement. But I think none of them will be as fancy and stylo as slide-push-menus ;) 
regards, zY